# Remove duplicated matching values from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
 $arrempty =array();

 for($i=0;$i<count($courseinfo['olinelist']);$i++){
     if(!in_array($courseinfo['olinelist'][$i]['onday'],$arrempty)){
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($courseinfo['olinelist']);
     }
 }

INPUT:
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23
    [onday] => 1
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 08:30:00
    [cd_desc] => REGISTRATION
    [end_time] => 09:00:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 145464959476.jpg
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23
    [onday] => 1
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 09:30:00
    [cd_desc] => ON LABEL VS OFF LABEL (BOTOX)
    [end_time] => 09:45:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 145464959476.jpg
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23
    [onday] => 2
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 09:00:00
    [cd_desc] => INTRODUCTION
    [end_time] => 09:15:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 145464959476.jpg
)

Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-20
    [onday] => 2
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 01:00:00
    [cd_desc] => Lunch
    [end_time] => 02:15:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 146.jpg
)

Output:

    date => 
    onday => 1
    session => 
    start_time => 08:30:00
    cd_desc => REGISTRATION
    end_time => 09:00:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 145464959476.jpg

    date => 
    onday => 
    session => 
    start_time => 09:30:00
    cd_desc => ON LABEL VS OFF LABEL (BOTOX)
    end_time => 09:45:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 145464959476.jpg

    date => 
    onday => 2
    session => 
    start_time => 09:00:00
    cd_desc => INTRODUCTION
    end_time => 09:15:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 145464959476.jpg

    date => 
    onday => 
    session => 
    start_time => 01:00:00
    cd_desc => Lunch
    end_time => 02:15:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 146.jpg
```

Look at date, onday and session should be blank while displaying into for each loop

what I want to do is to remove duplicate element values from array and keep key as blank. I have tried to use array_unique($myarray) , but it seem not working. Please help!!!

Comment: You're never adding anything to `$arrempty`?

Comment: That's why it's not working here. if you have any new idea it's always welcome

Comment: You could for example replace `print_r( $courseinfo['olinelist'] );` with `$arrempty[] = $courseinfo['olinelist'][$i]['onday']; print_r( $courseinfo['olinelist'][$i] );`

Comment: No Bhai... it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $arrempty =array();

 for($i=0;$i<count($courseinfo['olinelist']);$i++){
     if(!in_array($courseinfo['olinelist'][$i]['onday'],$arrempty['onday'])){
         $arrempty[] = $courseinfo['olinelist'][$i];
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($courseinfo['olinelist'][$i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given